# Jackrabbit nt:folder nt:file exception

Tags: jackrabbit

i am trying to add a child node to a nt:folder node (rep:AuthorizableFolder node actually, but the same problem arises with other node types). In the lines below the folder node appears in the path as **USUARIO-1311259687502**.

Saw your examples and some similar more, but the following line:

```
        **Node fileNode = folderNode.addNode(file.getName(), "nt:file");**
```

throws the following exception:

**Exception in thread "main" javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No child node definition for lebAudio.mp3 found in node /rep:security/rep:authorizables/rep:users/USUARIO-1311259687502**

Despite of having read some docu about node types (and understanding that nt:file is allowed as nt:folder child, and both are built-in types in Jackrabbit, so nothing special should be done) i do not understand what is wrong. Any idea?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

`rep:AuthorizableFolder` is not a sub type of `nt:Folder`. It does not allow you to add `nt:File` nodes.

Everything under `/rep:security` is used by Jackrabbit to manage security related things like user, groups and memberships. You should not alter the structures there.